# SQL Command Not Properly Ended driving me bananas

Tags: sql, ora-00933

I am trying to run this query, but i repeatedly get an error message.  Any suggestions?

```
SELECT DD_INTERVAL, VENDOR_ID, COUNTRY, "SUM"(VOLUME) as Volume, "SUM"(COST) as Cost
FROM Table_1
WHERE VENDOR_ID ='35',
    DD_INTERVAL = '7',
    COUNTRY = ('idn','lao','mys','phl','sgp','tha','vnm')
GROUP BY DD_INTERVAL, Vendor_ID, COUNTRY;
```

Comment: Whats your error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know about SQL your query should look like this

```
SELECT DD_INTERVAL, VENDOR_ID, COUNTRY, SUM(VOLUME) as Volume, SUM(COST) as Cost
FROM Table_1
WHERE VENDOR_ID ='35'
AND DD_INTERVAL = '7'
AND COUNTRY IN ('idn','lao','mys','phl','sgp','tha','vnm')
GROUP BY DD_INTERVAL, Vendor_ID, COUNTRY;
```

1. Quotes should not be around the `SUM`
2. You need a `AND` or `OR` between each where clause depending the result your looking for.
3. your `COUNTRY =` should be 
   `COUNTRY IN`